# Listing a list of Objects - Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm trying to do this:
I got 2 classes:

```java
public class Film{
    private int idFilm;
    private String titleFilm;
    private Actor actor;

    //getters and setters
}
```

```java
public class Actor{
    private int idActor;
    private String nameActor;
    private String lastNameActor;

    //getters and setters
}
```

Now, the point is:
When I do a consult with my database(I'm using Hibernate also)
What I do to display the list is:

```html
<c:forEach items="${list}" var="film">
    <tr>
        <td><c:out value="${film.titleFilm}"></c:out></td>
        <td><c:out value="${film.actor.nameActor}"></c:out></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

When I execute:

```html
<c:out value="${film.titleFilm}"></c:out>
```

It runs perfectly.

BUT, when I execute:

```html
<c:out value="${film.actor.nameActor}"></c:out>
```

It appears an error.

Help me guys, what would I do?

Comment: What error do you see? Could you show getter for `nameActor` property in `Actor` class?

Comment: Make sure property `actor` in object of class Film has data. Otherwise you might got NPE I guess.

Comment: `actor` should be `null` or getter may not correct

Comment: You may get a LazyInitializedException from Hibernate if you did not retrieved the films fetch join actors. Once you are in the JSP, I guess your Hibernate session is closed. So Hibernate cannot lazy load the actors of your film. This is one hypothesis. But you should definitely provide the Exception stack trace you get.

Comment: Comencau thanks, I put LazyInitializedException configuration, now it works!!! thanks